# How to use call back to make a function execute after another in setTimeout condition

Tags: javascript

I have some code which can be mimicked by this situation

```js
function abc(def){
    setTimeout(1500,function(){
        console.log('1');
    }
    def();
}

function def(){
    console.log('2'}
}
```

I want `2` to be printed after `1` - how do I do that?

Comment: Just add this line: `console.log('12');`

Comment: ...or put `def()` call at the end of the `anonymous` function used on `setTimeout()`, assuming you are calling `abc()` like `abc(def)`, i.e, you are passing `def` method as the argument of `abc`.

Comment: It's not too clear what you're asking but what about putting the call to def(); right after console.log("1"); inside the callback function?

Comment: I want to understand how call back works even if I called function inside from another function it is getting executed before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to also be called after a delay... just put it inside the delay.  I've added some extra console logs and fixed some of your code.  Run the below example to see how it works.

```js
function def() {
  console.log('2 - def()');
}

function abc() {
  console.log('before');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1');
    def();
  }, 1500);
  console.log('after');
}



abc();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc(def){
   setTimeout(1500,function(){
       console.log('1');
       def();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` and `await`. Wrap the `setTimeout(...)` in a Promise and resolve Promise inside the callback passed to `setTimeout`.

```js
async function abc(def){
    await new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('1');
        res();
      },1500)
    })
    def();
}

function def(){
    console.log('2')
}
abc(def)
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(function, milliseconds)` takes a function has the first parameter and delay value (time in milliseconds) as the second parameter. You were passing them in the wrong order.

Also in your example def() was printing 2 and it was outside the setTimeout function, so it could not have possibly printed 2 after 1 (as 1 was being logged inside the setTimeout, which means it would be executed after the delay of 1.5 seconds).

The solution provided by Chris above is correct and would do what you wanted (print 2 and then 1)